# iOS - onload not working

Tags: ios, redirect, orientation

I am trying to load up 2 different pages depending on what apple device I am using. I am doing this by checking the width of the device and then loading up 1 of 2 pages, my code is:

JavaScript:

```
function init() 
{
    if (screen.width <500)
    {
        window.open("home_phone.html");
    }
    else if (screen.width>=500)
    {
        window.open("home_iPad.html");
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<body onLoad="init();">
</body>
```

This should essentially load up 2 dfferent home pages. However for some reason it does not. It runs the function (tested using alerts), however does not load the page.

I then when on to test the function itself by adding a link which referred to the same init() function and the link worked fine.

Any ideas how i can get this to load up on the intial page load.

Thanks.

Comment: Does it help if you add some content inside the body element?

Comment: I had added a link something like this <a href="#" onClick="init();)>Function</a> This was basically refernecing the same function, the only difference being this link actually worked.

Comment: Sounds like it's a problem with your browser. But eventually give the code in my answer a try... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me your code works if I use `window.location=` instead of `window.open()`.
I don't know if that is acceptable for you, but your code would then look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function init()
{
    if (screen.width<500)
    {
        window.location = "home_phone.html";
    }
    else if (screen.width>=500)
    {
        window.location = "home_iPad.html";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="init();">

</body>
</html>
```

I hope this works for you. (If not try eventually another browser like Firefox or Chrome.)

Answer (score 0):

I do this:

```
window.location.href = "URL.HTML";
```

Comment: This also works perfectly fine, although it seems that the .href is not required. Thanks for the fix